# Start laptop without power button

Tags: button, remapping

I own a really old laptop (about 9 years old). It runs well, except for occasional hitches.

Few months ago, the power button stopped working gradually. The power button that started laptop on the first press, required multiple presses, until finally the button stopped working. A few days later when I took it to the repair shop, the damn thing worked on the first press, without even trying to figure out what was wrong! It kind of fixed itself!

Now, again I've been having this issue. I was wondering if I can use other buttons on my laptop to power on. I own a VAIO laptop that has ASSIST, WEB, and VAIO buttons apart from the power button. Is there a way to map start/restart functions to these?

Comment: Think the power button is mechanical, not software.  Would need to repair or replace/bypass.  Might just be dirty or sounds like a loose connection somewhere(might not be at button).  By moving the laptop to repair shop and having it work, my money is on a loose connection, weak solder joint or partial broken wire.  Would need a tear down of laptop to check,  google your laptop and will find videos and instructions on how-to.

Comment: Wake-on-LAN by [magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) from Ethernet may be an option. Not sure about its support in the BIOS.